# SQL to get number of working days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, days

I need to get number of "Working days" between any 2 given dates, and for that purpose i tried this query, which works perfectly, but I can't understand a part of it. Please anyone explain it to me:

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(dd, '2015-01-04', '2015-01-10') + 1)-
        (DATEDIFF(wk, '2015-01-04', '2015-01-10') * 2)-
        (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, '2015-01-04') = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-
        (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, '2015-01-10') = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

I know this much:

- First line gets all days inclusive the given dates.
- Second line check number of weeks falling in between these days, so subtracts the required weekends from the total days

Now I'm confused about the last two lines. It check if first date is a Sunday then subtract 1 from total, likewise for the last date to be a Saturday. **But what if first date is a SATURDAY and Last date is SUNDAY?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line removes the partial weeks, which only happens when the start date falls on a Sunday and the last date falls on a Saturday.

The second line,`(DATEDIFF(wk, '2015-01-04', '2015-01-10') * 2)`, counts whole weekends, that is a `Saturday-Sunday` pair. So in your question, if the first date is a `Saturday` , then it will count as one `Saturday-Sunday` pair. Same will be applied if the last date falls on a `Sunday`.